# Can I create my own bashrc file, something like ".xyzrc" and then import it from .bashrc?

Tags: bash

I want to put my dot files on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) , but I don't want all my aliases showing up publicly. So my plan is to put my aliases in a seperate file and `.gitignore` it. However I get a permission denied when I attempt to source that file. Are bashfiles supposed to be either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`?

(Mac OS X 10.7, Bash version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11).)

Comment: If you just do `./.xyzrc`, your file needs to be executable, and as such you need to `chmod` it accordingly. Otherwise, you can always do `sh .xyzrc`, which only requires reading rights. (Writing as a comment, because the question will probably be migrated to superuser.com.)

Comment: @zneak: anyways, doing _either_ `./.xyzrc` or `sh .xyzrc` will not affect the current shell (because they spawn subshells). See other answer :)

Comment: My bad. This should have been asked in superuser. Probably why I couldn't find similar questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is possible, and also a very good practice. However, as per your message of denied permission, maybe you're trying to execute that files. But to correctly read those files at configuration time, you have to add either:

```
source ~/.yourfile
```

or

```
. ~/.yourfile
```

in your `.bashrc` file. (Note the space after the first dot, that is an alias for `source`).

Comment: Appreciate the answer. It seems so obvious now.